# VBoxManage command falied Xamarin android player error on windows

Tags: xamarin-studio, xamarin-android-player

After installing Xamarin studio and Xamarin android player along with Oracle VirtualBox. I have created demo code and installed Nexus 4 (kitkat) virtual device in Android player but after running application Xamarin Android player gets started but got following window with error.

[image]

Comment: Open the VirtualBox Manager and try to start it from there...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Network Connections -> Right click VirtualBox Host-Only Network -> Properties -> Enable (or Disable then Enable) "VirtualBox NDIS6 Bridged Networking Driver"

Answer (score 1):

I found another question similar to the current question. see it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35526592/561256)

If you are using windows 10 then you need to have latest version of virtual box installed. you can get it from [Virtual Box Downloads page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

I hope it helps.