# xamarin android player failed to initialize device vboxmanag

Tags: xamarin-android-player

I have recently installed a xamarin android player for developing android application but after the complete installation when i open a xamarin android player it will throw a following error...

****xamarin android player failed to initialize device vboxmanag****

Can anyone help me or tell me what can I do.

Comment: What version of Xamarin Android Player do you have installed? Also what operating system are you using?

Comment: I'm using windows 10 64 bit OS and  Xamarin version 0.6.5.0

Comment: What version of Virtual Box is installed? When you open Xamarin Android Player directly do you receive the failure to initialize error or at another point? And have you downloaded any device images yet?

Comment: Virtual Box 5.0. and when I open a Xamarin android player it will through the following error .. Failed to initialize Device...  VBoxManage command fail

Comment: What happens when you open Virtual Box directly?

Comment: i have the same error :( Windows 10 64bit, Virtual Box 5.0.4

Answer (score 5):

I am running `Windows 10 Pro` and use Oracle VBox v.`5.0.4`. 
if your case same with me : first, you need to uninstall the current version of Oracle VBox then install the new version that already support Windows 10. i use v. `5.1.` You can download it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_1)

then, just try to re-launch the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I found some info by Googling around that may help starting a device in the Android Player. I have Vers 0.6.5 of the player.

1. Open VirtualBox directly as suggested by Cook Data. You will get the REAL error message which may related to vt-ix....
2. Make sure that the the bios has enabled the virtual technology aka vt-ix. Just do a reboot and you should find it in he bios setup - maybe under advanced. AMD and INTEL have slightly different names for it.
3. Reduce the system memory for the device you wish to start to 1024 Mb if it is currently 2048 Mb

I also got a warning about video memory which I increased to 10Mb from 8Mb

My setup runs over Hyper-V which has its own foibles so YMMV and I only started on this stuff today...

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 users
(After Bios Virtualization enabled)
Use VirtualBox 5.1.14
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...